# How to reverse date format in XSLT?

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

I’m working on a site In that site  some pages gets data from XML through XSLT. But the date is displayed as YYYY-MM-DD which ideally is taken from the XML which was in this format. I would like to convert this format to DD-MM-YYYY through XSLT or some other possible way.

Please suggest me an idea to go ahead or provide me the code to achieve this ASAP.
This is the format of xml giving

```
 <published date="2009-09-28T07:06:00 CET" />
```

and i want to convert this into

```
 <published date="28-09-2009T07:06:00 CET" />
```

and this is xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table class="bdr-bot" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="clear:both">
          <tr>
            <th width="15%" class="bdr">Date</th>
            <th class="bdr">Title</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="hexML/body/press_releases/press_release">
          <xsl:if test="contains(published/@date, '2009')">
            <tr>
              <td valign="top">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(published/@date, 'T')"/>
              </td>
              <td valign="top">
              <a href="result-page.aspx?ResultPageURL={location/@href}"><xsl:value-of select="headline"/></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
```

Now tell me the solution? is this possible with **fn:reverse**?

Comment: As the XSLT is highly dependent of the XML stucture, it would be easier if you could provide a sample.

Comment: I think that converting `"2009-09-28T07:06:00 CET"` to `"28-09-2009T07:06:00 CET"` is an excercise in futility. The former is a defined date format, the latter is not. Why would you want to transform a common, standardized format into something ambiguous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also use a template.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <html>
      <body>
        <table class="bdr-bot" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="clear:both">
          <tr>
            <th width="15%" class="bdr">Date</th>
            <th class="bdr">Title</th>
          </tr>
         <!-- <xsl:for-each select="hexML/body/press_releases/press_release">-->
            <xsl:if test="contains(published/@date, '2009')">
              <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                  <xsl:call-template name="FormatDate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="DateTime" select="published/@date"/>
                  </xsl:call-template>
                </td>
                  <td valign="top">
                  <a href="result-page.aspx?ResultPageURL={location/@href}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="headline"/>
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:if>
          <!--</xsl:for-each>-->
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="FormatDate">
    <xsl:param name="DateTime"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($DateTime,9,2)"/>-<xsl:value-of select="substring($DateTime,6,2)"/>-<xsl:value-of select="substring($DateTime,1,4)"/><xsl:text> CET</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: i added more info to question

Comment: how can i set ur solution in my template?

Comment: I edited to more reflect your current xslt and the xml, I coomented out the loop as it was easier for me without you full xml but it should work, also I have assumed the CET is constant, if not you can add another substring for the last 3 characters.

Comment: is it also possible with fn:reverse?

Comment: it would probably be a little difficult, you would need to strip out the unused data like the time first and the time zone to just revers the date part of the string and then re-add the bit you needed like the timezone. I haven't really used that function in anger so maybe someone else would now in better detail

Comment: only because I didnt have the full XML to hand, you can fit it back in easily

Answer (score 3):

If the XML is in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, you should be able to use Xpath's `tokenize` function to split up your string where `-` occurs, and then reorder it. Something akin to:

```
<xsl:variable name="dt" value="tokenize(Date, '-')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(dt[3],'-',dt[2],'-',dt[1])"/>
```

This is just off the top of my head (and untested), but you get the general idea. You should be able to split up the date and reorder the pieces.

Comment: Most efficient! However, you have a couple syntax errors. The attribute in `\xsl:variable` should be `select` instead of `value`. And a $ should precede `dt` when you reference the variable in the second line: `$dt[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

```
<xml>
  <date>2009-11-18</date>
</xml>
```

This XSLT 1.0 solution would do it:

```
<xsl:template match="date">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="
      concat(
        substring(., 9, 2),
        '-',
        substring(., 6, 2),
        '-',
        substring(., 1, 4)
      )
    " />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If your date can be

```
<xml>
  <date>2009-11-1</date>
</xml>
```

you would have to use the slightly more complicated

```
<xsl:template match="date">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="
      concat(
        substring-after(substring-after(., '-'), '-'), 
        '-',
        substring-before(substring-after(., '-'), '-'), 
        '-',
        substring-before(., '-')
      )
    " />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need to use an XSLT 2.0 schema aware processor to get built-in support for what you want to do with the xs:dateTime data type and the format-date function.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime for the requirements for XSLT 2.0 being able to parse the string you have.

> The ·lexical space· of dateTime
>   consists of finite-length sequences of
>   characters of the form: '-'? yyyy '-'
>   mm '-' dd 'T' hh ':' mm ':' ss ('.'
>   s+)? (zzzzzz)?

See http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/rev2/dates.html#d16685e16 for generating output.

> format-date(   xs:date(
>       concat(
>         substring($d,1,4),
>         '-',
>         substring($d,7,2),
>         '-',
>         substring($d,5,2))),
>       '[D01] [MNn] [Y0001]')